# Exception Value:failed to find libmagic. Check your installation in windows 11?

Tags: python-magic, libmagic

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlQMv.png)

[Error during the libmagic installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6gHj.png)

When i am doing lanchain + gpt + python project using jupyter notebook its always shows this error. I installed libmagic and I also installed python magic. I have done pipi install python-magic-bin , pip install python-magic-bin==0.4.14, pip install python-libmagic etc like different installations.